# mono for android error CopyGeneratedJavaResourceClasses

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, fips

I am installing mono for android on my pc

I installed Xamarin Installer for Mono for Android when the installer finished

I opened MonoDevelop and created new android project and get this error

```
> C:\Program Files
> (x86)\MSBuild\Novell\Novell.MonoDroid.Common.targets(2,2): Error
> MSB4018: The "CopyGeneratedJavaResourceClasses" task failed
> unexpectedly.
> 
> System.InvalidOperationException: This implementation is not part of
> the Windows Platform FIPS validated cryptographic algorithms.
> 
>    at System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1Managed..ctor()
> 
>    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.MonoAndroidHelper.HashFile(String
> filename)
> 
>    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.MonoAndroidHelper.HasFileChanged(String
> source, String destination)
> 
>    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.MonoAndroidHelper.CopyIfChanged(String
> source, String destination)
> 
>    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.CopyGeneratedJavaResourceClasses.Execute()
> 
>    at
> Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
> 
>    at
> Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost
> taskExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, TaskHost
> taskHost, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask,
> Boolean& taskResult) (MSB4018) (rrr)
```

and when I tried to create new android project in Visual Studio 2010 I got this error too
please help!

Answer (score 2):

It seems that FIPS 140 compliance is [enabled](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2005/05/16/417975.aspx) on your computer. This will disallow non-FIPS certified algorithms to be executed.

E.g. Microsoft's `SHA1Managed` is not certified, while `SHA1CryptoServiceManager` uses CryptoAPI and *should* be ok - it really depends on platforms and versions.

The *easy* workaround is to [turn off](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/811833) FIPS compliance on your computer (see notes for registry keys).